# How to find all products by array of Characteristic ids

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm very new to the databases, so don't even know how to that.

I have a Product with a few relations, and i need to find all products which related to one category, and related to a few characteristics, but if i'm trying to wrote an array inside `include.where`, i'm getting an empty array of products from postgres

```
Product.findAndCountAll({
    limit,
    offset,
    order: [order],
    include: [
      { model: db.ProductMeta },
      {
        model: db.Characteristic,
        where: { id: [1, 2] },
      },
      {
        model: db.Category,
        where: { id: categoryId },
      },
    ],
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the operator `Op.in` in the case you want to check against several values:

```js
Product.findAndCountAll({
    limit,
    offset,
    order: [order],
    include: [
      { model: db.ProductMeta },
      {
        model: db.Characteristic,
        where: {
          id: {
            [Op.in]: [1, 2] 
          }
        },
      },
      {
        model: db.Category,
        where: { id: categoryId },
      },
    ],
  });
```